# MySQL Foreign-Keys: Because of understanding RESTRICT & UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 2 tables:

1) kind_basis (child-basis-data)

```
id              bigint(20) unsigned     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
vorname         varchar(64)             NO          NULL
nachname        varchar(64)             NO          NULL
geburtsland_id  bigint(20) unsigned     NO  MUL     NULL
```

2) liste_land (list of countries)

```
id              bigint(20) unsigned     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
iso             varchar(2)              NO          NULL
landname        varchar(255)            NO          NULL
```

There is a releation between them:

```
ALTER TABLE `kind_basis` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_geburtsland_id` 
    FOREIGN KEY ( `geburtsland_id` ) 
    REFERENCES `liste_land` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

Why is following-query is possible?

```
DELETE 
    FROM  `liste_land` 
    WHERE `liste_land`.`id` = 6
```

Shouldn't I get such of a message "You may not delete the row, because it is used in an another table (kind_basis) ?

If I update a row in liste_land, will it be also updated in kind_basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON DELETE RESTRICT` means you can't delete a  parent row if a child row  references the value for that parent so you probably dont have that child row.

Comment: what is parent, what is child in my case above?

Comment: Child is the table where the foreign key is,parent is the referenced table(liste_land)

Comment: But I can succesfully delete a row in the parent-table (liste_land) although there is a reference on it (from kind_basis -> on delete -> restrict). What is my mistake in reasoning?

Comment: On geburtsland_id in kind_basis and on id in liste_land you have to have the value 6 for the DELETE RESTRICT to kick in,in your example.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, the value has to be exist before?

Comment: Yes,foreign key means a relation defined on a column in both tables:a 6 value one 1 column corresponds with the 6 on the other column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to delete because it puts the table you are using all the data at once, avoids mistakes, avoid breaking your head and try to decipher pinching, or simply why not try to use another tool to develop these tables oracle , has mysqlWorkbench which is very good super easy and has many videos on youtube his classes, as I'm sure you already have the wisdom of creation and manipulation is easy, my tip invez try to delete or update creates a new table already entities and attributes that you need to not have to keep updating or deleting and then import it to where you want

Comment: Regarding, "If I update a row in liste_land, will it be also updated in kind_basis? ", no.

Comment: It depends on the update.  In your example, you were looking to delete the primary key of the parent table.  That probably would not be permitted because of the foreign key, which is good.  However, if you were simply updating another field, the records in the child table would not be affected, but queries involving both tables would return the new value from the parent table.  This would come in handy if, for example, you spelled a country name wrong and didn't notice for awhile.  You could simply correct it in the liste_land table and the job would be done.